# SSRS ReportService - Can you upload images (png/jpeg)?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We have several reports that use .png images for company logos in the header of the reports.

We are deploying reports using the SQL SSRS 2010 webservice. The idea is that the deployment must be done automatically with a script that invokes the SSRS webservice, and it must be 100% unattended

So far, we've successfully uploaded the reports, however, we are not sure how to upload the .png images

Is there any of the webservices methods that can accomplish this? Or is there a way to copy the file directly to somewhere

Comment: Have you set the images to embedded?

Comment: That works, if I set the image as embedded and then upload the report, the image can be visualized!

Do you want to post it as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the image as embedded then the image will be encoded with the .rdl file and you don't have top worry about copying the images.